# flutter location package version conflict with google_map_location_picker

Tags: flutter, dart, pubspec

I download a source code from codecanyone but
I am facing the following issue when  adding  google_map_location_picker package

> Because location 4.3.0 depends on location_platform_interface ^2.3.0 and no versions of location_platform_interface match >2.3.0 <3.0.0, location 4.3.0 requires location_platform_interface 2.3.0.
> And because location_platform_interface 2.3.0 depends on plugin_platform_interface ^2.0.0 and geolocator_platform_interface <2.0.0-nullsafety.0 depends on plugin_platform_interface ^1.0.2, location 4.3.0 is incompatible with geolocator_platform_interface <2.0.0-nullsafety.0.
> And because google_map_location_picker >=4.1.3 depends on geolocator ^6.1.14 which depends on geolocator_platform_interface ^1.0.8, location 4.3.0 is incompatible with google_map_location_picker >=4.1.3.
> So, because markets depends on both google_map_location_picker 4.1.7 and location 4.3.0, version solving failed.
> pub get failed (1; So, because markets depends on both google_map_location_picker 4.1.7 and location 4.3.0, version solving failed.)

here is my pubspec.yaml file

```html
name: markets
description: markets

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 2.2.0

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0"
module:
  androidX: true
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: 1.0.4
  google_maps_flutter: 2.1.1
  google_map_location_picker: 4.1.7
  mvc_pattern: 6.6.4+2
  global_configuration: 2.0.0-nullsafety.1
  html: 0.15.0
  shared_preferences: 2.0.13
  flutter_html: 3.0.0-alpha.2
  flutter_svg: 1.0.3
  location: 4.3.0
  webview_flutter: 3.0.0
  url_launcher: 6.0.20
  cached_network_image: 3.2.0
  fluttertoast: 8.0.8
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: 0.4.0-nullsafety.3
  intl_utils: 2.6.1
  carousel_slider: 4.0.0
  cloud_firestore: 3.1.8
  firebase_auth: 3.3.7
  firebase_core: 1.12.0
  firebase_messaging: 11.2.6
  firebase_storage: 8.0.0
  image_picker: 0.7.5+4
  string_validator: 0.3.0
  platform: 3.1.0


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/cfg/
    - assets/img/

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  fonts:
    - family: ProductSans
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/ProductSans-Thin.ttf
          weight: 100
        - asset: assets/fonts/ProductSans-Thin.ttf
          weight: 200
        - asset: assets/fonts/ProductSans-Light.ttf
          weight: 300
        - asset: assets/fonts/ProductSans-Regular.ttf
          weight: 400
        - asset: assets/fonts/ProductSans-Medium.ttf
          weight: 500
        - asset: assets/fonts/ProductSans-Bold.ttf
          weight: 600
        - asset: assets/fonts/ProductSans-Black.ttf
          weight: 700
        - asset: assets/fonts/ProductSans-Black.ttf
          weight: 800
        - asset: assets/fonts/ProductSans-Black.ttf
          weight: 900
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: assets/fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: assets/fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-assets/fonts/#from-packages
flutter_intl:
  enabled: true
```

Comment: Didy you try to use another version of "location"? If you can and your project accepts it, try to replace location line with "location: ^4.1.1" or even 4.0.2 and see from there using the command flutter pub outdated to see if you can update to any newer version looking at the column "upgradable"

Comment: https://flutterrepos.com/lib/fysoul17-google_maps_place_picker-flutter-map Did you check this sample? It might need adjustments but its using google maps package. Because that package you're trying to use is old, 16 months since last change and it depends on a very old version of plugin_platform_interface, one that is not even migrated to null safety

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just stumbled upon a Dependency Hell. [google_map_location_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/google_map_location_picker) is pretty old now (16 months already) and it uses outdated versions of other packages that some dependencies from the `pubspec.yaml` depends on itself.

If you remove `google_map_location_picker` from the dependencies everything installs smoothly. Your best option then would be to fork `google_map_location_picker` and change the dependencies yourself and point its dependency in the `pubspec.yaml` to this fork of yours.

To add the fork as a dependency, for example from Github, do something like this:

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  carousel_pro:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/your_account/google_map_location_picker_fork.git
      ref: main # branch name
```